# Create 3 blocks in a 2-1 layout in beamer

Tags: beamer, lyx

Is it possible to create 3 blocks in a single frame in beamer with a distribution as shown in the image below? The blocks must have the same width, and block C should be centered.

```
-----   -----
| A |   | B |
-----   -----
    -----
    | C |
    -----
```

Comment: You may have to resort to ERTs though...

Answer (score 5):

One way to do this is with the help of some boxes.

1. Inside a frame, add first an ERT with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> and write `\centering` inside this.
2. Do Insert --> Box --> Frameless.
3. Right click the 'header' of the box, and click *Settings*. Set the width to for example 40% of the column width.
4. Add a block inside this box, by selecting *Block* from the style drop down menu.
5. Place the cursor just outside the box, and repeat steps 2-4. (Or you can simply copy-paste the first box with block.)
6. (Optionally) Place the cursor between the two boxes, and add some horizontal space with Insert --> Formatting --> Horizontal space. Using *Horizontal Fill* will push the to blocks to the edges.
7. Place the cursor after the second box and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Optionally add some vertical space.
8. Repeat steps 2-4 (or copy/paste one of the other boxes) to add the third box with block.

Here is how this can look in LyX and in the PDF:

[image]

And here is the `.lyx` file itself. (Copy the code, paste it into a text editor, save as `something.lyx`.)

```
#LyX 2.1 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 474
\begin_document
\begin_header
\textclass beamer
\begin_preamble
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\end_preamble
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman default
\font_sans default
\font_typewriter default
\font_math auto
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100
\font_tt_scale 100
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 1
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry true
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 0
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 0
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 0
\use_package stmaryrd 0
\use_package undertilde 0
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Frame

\end_layout

\begin_layout Frame
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
centering
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Frame

\end_layout

\begin_layout Frame

\end_layout

\begin_layout Frame

\end_layout

\begin_layout Frame

\end_layout

\begin_layout Frame

\end_layout

\begin_layout Frame
\begin_inset Box Frameless
position "t"
hor_pos "c"
has_inner_box 1
inner_pos "t"
use_parbox 0
use_makebox 0
width "40col%"
special "none"
height "1in"
height_special "totalheight"
status open

\begin_layout Block
\begin_inset Argument 2
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout
First block
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Block
Block 1 content
\end_layout

\end_inset


\begin_inset space \hfill{}
\end_inset


\begin_inset Box Frameless
position "t"
hor_pos "c"
has_inner_box 1
inner_pos "t"
use_parbox 0
use_makebox 0
width "40col%"
special "none"
height "1in"
height_special "totalheight"
status open

\begin_layout Block
\begin_inset Argument 2
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout
Second block
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Block
Block 2 content
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Frame
\begin_inset VSpace 0.5cm
\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Frame
\begin_inset Box Frameless
position "t"
hor_pos "c"
has_inner_box 1
inner_pos "t"
use_parbox 0
use_makebox 0
width "40col%"
special "none"
height "1in"
height_special "totalheight"
status open

\begin_layout Block
\begin_inset Argument 2
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout
First block
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Block
Block 1 content
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Answer (score 1):

With `tcolorbox`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{myblock}[1]{beamer, width=.475\linewidth,title=#1,on line}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{myblock}{First block}
Some text
\end{myblock}\hfill
\begin{myblock}{Second block}
Some text
\end{myblock}
\bigskip
{\par\centering
\begin{myblock}{Third block}
Some text
\end{myblock}
\par}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `minipages` and `beamer` blocks.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\linewidth}
\begin{block}{First block}
Some text
\end{block}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\linewidth}
\begin{block}{Second block}
Some text
\end{block}
\end{minipage}
\bigskip
{\par\centering
\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\linewidth}
\begin{block}{Third block}
Some text
\end{block}
\end{minipage}
\par}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A similar result can be obtained with beamer's `beamerboxesrounded` boxes and `columns`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
\column{.45\linewidth}
\begin{beamerboxesrounded}[width=\linewidth,shadow]{First block}
Some text
\end{beamerboxesrounded}%
\column{.45\linewidth}
\begin{beamerboxesrounded}[width=\linewidth,shadow]{Second block}
Some text
\end{beamerboxesrounded}
\end{columns}
\bigskip
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
\column{.275\linewidth}
\column{.45\linewidth}
\begin{beamerboxesrounded}[width=\linewidth,shadow]{Third block}
Some text
\end{beamerboxesrounded}
\column{.275\linewidth}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```